# Concatenate columns inside ArrayFormula, excluding certain values

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Please see the Google Sheet at the link below. In column 'F', I need to use an ARRAYFORMULA to combine the values from columns 'B' through 'E', separating the values with commas, and excluding the values that read "No". Column G shows the desired output of the `ARRAYFORMULA`.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GMOU0I4v1TcyBAnTDKPfccGWO9LYoM8_wz6hx_JXg0/edit?usp=sharing

Edit: Both answers below solve the problem. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B)>0, REGEXREPLACE(transpose( 
             query(transpose({B2:C, E2:E, G2:G})&",",,9^9)),"(No, )|(, No)|(,$)",""),""))
```

[image]

Comment: That works for the updated sheet, thank you marikamitsos!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF((B2:E="")+(B2:E="no"),,B2:E&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(({B2:C, E2:E, G2:G}="")+
    ({B2:C, E2:E, G2:G}="no"),,
     {B2:C, E2:E, G2:G}&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, player0!

Comment: player0, I just realized your solution won't work for my actual application because there are columns in between that shouldn't be included. I've edited the sample sheet to better reflect this. Sorry about that! Do you think you can devise a new solution?